# Cocoa parse line of data like perl regex

Tags: cocoa, parsing

What is the most efficient way to parse a line of data similar to how perl regex does?  For example, if the line of data is: "username!ABCD!123-123-0000", I could use this perl expression to parse the data:
`data =~ /([A-z]+)!([A-F]+)!([0-9]+)-(.+)/`

This causes `$1=username, $2=ABCD, $3=123, $4=123-0000`

Is there a way to do this in Cocoa?  Even solutions that predefine 4 NSString variables are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following pattern:

```
username!tag!password
```

And the following requirements:

- The username may only contain `A-Z` and `a-z`.
- The tag may only contain `A-F`.
- The password may only contain `0-9` and `-`.

One method to extract and validate the values:

```
NSString *input = @"username!ABCD!123-123-0000";

NSArray *split = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"!"];

NSString *user = [split objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tag  = [split objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *pass = [split objectAtIndex:2];

NSCharacterSet *checkUser = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
NSCharacterSet *checkTag  = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEF"];
NSCharacterSet *checkPass = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-"];

if ( [[user stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:checkUser] length] == 0 ) NSLog(@"User \"%@\" is valid.",user);
if ( [[tag  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:checkTag ] length] == 0 ) NSLog(@"Tag \"%@\" is valid.", tag );
if ( [[pass stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:checkPass] length] == 0 ) NSLog(@"Pass \"%@\" is valid.",pass);
```

Output:

```
User "username" is valid.
Tag "ABCD" is valid.
Pass "123-123-0000" is valid.
```

You may also consider using `NSScanner` or `NSRegularExpression`.